# Rename file on firebase storage and keep old url

Tags: android-studio, firebase-storage

I have a doubt, can I save an image in "storage" with the same name and identification of another existing image?
As if I wanted to rename the new image with the name of the old one.
I'm creating a system where I have to update an image, however, it is used in several other places through the url, when I change the image, it also changes the url. is there any method to maintain the old url?

Comment: Are you storing the results of `getDownloadURL()` somewhere, or are you calling it each time your need the file's URL?

Comment: I keep the url in an individual record in the batabase, to be retrieved and used later.